# Instant reloading bullets

Tags: science-fiction, scientific-development, teleportation

I have a hero who uses a pair of handguns as weapons. As he progresses along his journey he's obviously going to become better and better with them as well as run into tougher and more numerous villains. The problem will arise as to how to keep him stocked with ammunition in order for him to battle his foes. I've thought of a concept in which on command, he could touch a sensor on the grips and have them reload by teleporting bullets from his base directly into the clips instantaneously. My working idea in which to do this is to setup an ever growing network of transceivers throughout his city that triangulate the position of the guns so that the teleportation can take place accurately.

My question is, what scientific theory would best suit this type of technology so I can best understand how to evolve the idea? Or is this out of the realm of science and into sci-fi/fantasy where I can just do what I want and not have to explain it.

Comment: If I've not mistaken you wish for the spend ammo to return to its original last registered state at a distance or instantaneously, that violates causality; cause and effect cannot happens at the same time although nature is a serial perpetrator here!

Comment: Obligatory post for when an author thinks of simply adding teleportation tech/magic to his story: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJt8yzR2aoY

Comment: Scientific teleportation? Isn't it better to use non-material bullets, like in Star Wars?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/465/

Comment: What, and give up on having "hero is low on ammunition" as a plot situation?

Comment: So you are in a world so advanced teleportation exists but ammo is still required.....

Comment: Oh please, don't call them clips. They are "magazines".

Comment: Why not teleport the head off the bad guy's body? I spent all of star trek wondering why no one ever weaponized the teleporter like that, it would be easy.

Comment: There's not much in the way of science truth for teleportation, so you're going to have to use your imagination there.  However, one thing I would recommend considering: a *major* feature of guns is their simplicity.  They don't have very many exotic parts that can break or need batteries.  This is important because the people who use guns *need* them to work when they pull the trigger.  Consider having the teleporter work in a way such that, if the teleporter fails, you still have a full magazine of ammo to work with.

Comment: "touch a sensor"?? Who touches sensors? If you pull off teleportation but don't manage automatic reloading upon depletion of previous loads, you'll shatter my suspension of disbelief.

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar The sensor is on the trigger.  What he really means is that you have to fire offscreen to reload with his system!

Comment: @user137 The closest they came to that was probably the (modified) [TR-116 rifle](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/TR-116_rifle).

Comment: Wasn't there something like this in that Milla Jovovich film "Ultraviolent"? She had a pocket dimension to store weapons and ammo, IIRC. I don't recall if it automagically fed her ammo or just let her carry around a huge inventory without encumbrance.

Comment: Instead of teleportation bullets into his magazines, why not teleport literally anything inside the head of the bad guys?

Comment: @JasonK: more importantly with breaking the line of her clothes.

Comment: Is there any reason he couldn't take ammo off of his dead foes? it's a tried-and-true technique for a reason.

Comment: *I do not kill with my gun; he who kills with his gun has forgotten the face of his father. I kill with my heart.* Step one: don't ever miss. Step two: carry a bag with an unmentioned number of bullets (kept dry at all cost). Step three: use revolvers. Step four (the most important part): go read *The Dark Tower*.

Comment: Another point of vocabulary: The things-what-go-bang that the magazine contains are called "cartridges", not "bullets."  The bullet is the part of the cartridge that comes out of the barrel when the gun is fired.  I mention this because if you get the terminology wrong, readers who know the correct terminology may have trouble taking the story seriously.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I'm not going to teleport the rounds directly into the heads because that removes the skill factor I want. Part of the hero's allure is his creativity with combat. I don't want the spent ammo to be returned or recycled into the magazine. I want there to be a stockpile of ammunition in his hideout and be able to teleport bullets/cartridges/rounds directly into the magazine on command so there's no significant down time. Teleportation hasn't been invented in this world yet, except by another character in the story who is an ally of the Hero.

Comment: Your "skill" factor can come from your hero's ability to mark the teleportation site. As you mentioned, the location to be teleported to is non-trivial to park in 3D. Perhaps the "gun" could be an analog to the lasers that are set up to target smart bombs.

Comment: Bad title. "*Instant Reloading Bullets*" already exist, they're called Machine Guns and other fully-automatic weapons.  What you're asking about is "*Unlimited Weightless Ammo Supply*".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

---

## New Answer

> The teleportation technology hasn't been invented yet, except by another character in the story that is an ally of the hero. The hero has his own personal mad scientist buddy. (...) Think of the network as an underground type system. Designed for and utilized exclusively by the Hero.

So, let's start on the assumption that the network is privately used, built, and maintained the hero et al. and largely unknown to the rest of the world.

*Let me get this idea out there: Mommy, mommy, there is strange machine in the park... arghh! News report: Child found dead by presumed energy beam from a mysterious machine discovered in the park, a S.W.A.T team is on the way to dismantle the aparatus.*

The idea of an underground network for teleportation is similar in logistic to a [wireless mesh network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network). But people don't agree on a creating a single roaming WiFi with their routers. Instead each network has its own id and password, even if setting a single configuration would give WiFi internet to everybody virtually everywhere and virtually free. Yeah, privacy and "I'm paying this bill" are the main issues.

Of course hero et al. are not convincing people to do this, instead they are leaving strange machines in random spots on the city.

**The mad scientist is insane or is crazy rich:**

- The mad scientist buddy is not only mad, he is also rich. He has a lot of properties accross the city where this kind of stuff can sit legally without much problem. This also explain how he was able to do the research and development required to get a working teleportation device, and also explains who is manufacturing all the bullets that get teleported to the hero and paying for the maintenance of the network.
- The mad scientist buddy has little regard for the law. In fact, he doesn't care about private property... this machines end up in somebody's roof, the tree on another person's backyard, and at the end of some dark alley. They take their electricity from somebody's connection. The machines are low quality, and tend to fail. Who said repair? Better replace and scrap the old one for part - there ain't money for more. The teleported bullets are probably stolen. And when those machines start to pop on the news, the mad scientist buddy may find the desire to teleport himself out of town.

---

### Networking

Are there any wireless networks in operation already? Because it would be much more convenient if you could send instructions to the teleportation machines by - for example - the cell phone network.

---

The purpose of the network is to minimize the distance that the signal has to travel. That is, to minimize attenuation, and therefore allow you to operate with less energy. If that applies to teleportation (and why wouldn't) then you want to teleport the bullets from the nearest node.

The gun needs to communicate to the network. This is either done directly, in which case the node that gets the strongest signal is the appropriate. Or indirectly (with a third party network) in which case the gun reports its position and the nodes negotiate which one sends the bullets.

That implies that hero et al. needs to supply bullets to each node. Given that each node is able to teleport bullets and under the assumption that energy is a solved problem, you could feed them in any node and have them be teleported to the nodes that need them.

Then, if the nearest node to the hero has run out of bullets, it has to request them to the nearby nodes, which will teleport to them on demand. This adds a delay to teleportation.

---

### Optimization

Since this network is dedicated to a single type of thing only. And we are working under the idea that teleportation requires a receiver. There are is an optimization to be done: Pre-program the receivers to shape the particles that are received in a known way. This saves you sending the information of each object; they are - for all uses and purposes - identical. This implies that you don't need to pre-manufacture the objects, you just need the material.

A second optimization can be done by using mold if what you are sending is made of a single material and a very simple structure. There is a solution for that on [Daerdemandt's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/55786/16729) under "Don't use gunpowder". Daerdemandt suggest a railgun, that would work in this scenario. The drawback is that even a 2% efficiency coilgun is only deadly at point-blank range.

So, the hero has a this backpack where he has the receiver that get the material, prints the bullets and [then fed to the guns via a belt-like system attached to his arms (or even implanted?)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55705/instant-reloading-bullets).

And why do you need teleportation anyway? You can have thousands of railgun projectiles in the backpack.

---

**Of course, you want actual bullets**. The mad scientist is actually insane, and doesn't care about economy.

So, you need copper for the jacket, and lead for the core of the bullet. You also need brass for the cartridge case and of course gunpowder. The actual manufacturing work is done by pressure not by heating or molding.

There is a problem: you are building gunpowder with a highly energetic process. **Boom** (actually it will burn, not explode, as you would only have a small charge and it ain't under pressure, but "boom" is more dramatic). The workaround seems to be to mix the gunpowder on site, and then assamble the bullet. For that the backpack needs moving parts.

*And that is disregarding the problem of how teleportation actually works. Which you can see in my original answer below.*

---

### Alternative

Instead I will suggest an alternative: you can build a laser rifle with an array of laser LED, "beam combiners" and a two or three lens system to get the most of it. The problem is the energy, but if we say that you have a car battery in your backpack and you are using 80% efficient lasers, your output is around 380W (that's an array of about 500 LEDs, so the thing is more of a bazooka in shape and size). Regardless, the thing cooks like a toaster oven.

---

## Original Answer

This kind of technology would have too many implications. For starter, you will not only be able to deliver bullets, but drugs, food, etc... And the enemies of your hero would be able to.

> My working idea in which to do this is to setup an ever growing network of transceivers throughout his city that triangulate the position of the guns so that the teleportation can take place accurately.

And what about interference in the triangulation signal so your hero can't get bullets? - As for scientific theory, well, non-grounded in reality.

Let's consider how teleportation works:

- It may work by scanning the <strike>victim</strike> object, <strike>killing it</strike> disintegrating it, sending the particles, and reassembling them on the other side. This requires a wired connection or a high energy directional signal (aka. a energy beam) that goes form the source to the destination, and probably a complicated chamber where the reconstruction happens.
- Instead of the chamber, try manipulating individual particles at large distance. So, you don't only send the particles, you use a giant laser to move them around. Disregarding the problem of focusing the laser, you now need much more energy.
- Why do we have to send the particles that made the original? Instead we could just send the information and have it be constructed (3D printed) from materials at the destination. Now sending the information is not a problem, but the destination needs to have material to build the object. Of course, you aren't disintegrating the original anymore.
- Use quantum entanglement to push the target particles into the correct state. Ern... no, quantum entanglement doesn’t work that way. You need to have the particles interact for them to get entangled. So you either sending entangled particles to the destination or the destination have to carry pre-entangled particles. By the no-cloning theorem the original is destroyed to extract the information that is then transmitted by the entangled particles. So, it is the same situation as before, quantum entanglement bought you nothing.
- Use portals, I mean wormholes, well, [Nolo covered this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/55708/16729).

If you are going to disintegrate something, you need enough energy to move all of its particles, over whatever distance you want to move them. And you want to do it as fast as possible... light speed fast. But you can't because what you want to move has some mass. In fact, you think you are building a teleportation machine, but you are building a [particle-beam weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle-beam_weapon). Just shoot at the enemy.

Let's assume that teleportation just works:

- Accidents happen, like any means of transportation there relies on machinery (ie. everything except walking barefoot) depends on that machinery working correctly. It is expected that there would be malfunctions from time to time.
- Would it work on machines? If I can deploy a bullet, I can deploy a combat robot. *Oh, my setting doesn't have robots* - I wonder how technology evolved then. The evident uses of teleportation in the battle field include deploying troops, supplies, ammo, and weapons.
- The energy for the teleportation is not free; the hero could be required by law to pay for this service. In fact, similar technology could be useable to supply electricity or even water. If we go with the idea of the network, the infrastructure can't be built on teleportation; this means that teleportation is expensive. Teleporting something would be at least as expensive as the energy bill for the equivalent energy of the teleported mass... plus inflation (the network needs maintenance, also it is expanding, and somebody pays for that).
- At some point teleporting something is too expensive - because it is too large, or because the distance is too long - and then conventional transportation is used.
- The fact that the network is growing suggest that teleporting is a profitable business, so I would expect various commercial or industrial companies taking advantage of teleportation. I these companies consider teleportation cheap; it probably means that the region has other infrastructure problems (maybe it is an isolated location). On the other hand, these companies may be providing instantaneous delivery at high fees – and it is popular. *I wonder for what kind of things people may be willing to pay crazy money for the “right now” option, also, in what does people work to have money for this to be popular?*
- The above implies that "heroing" is has good revenue. I would expect it to be at least fairly common. It would be an activity similar to bounty hunting. Alternatively, the hero is not operating under the law.
- The bad guys don't pay (either they are criminal, or they are the government), they take advantage of the network, they make it so it won't give more bullets to the hero... or perhaps a [bullet on the chest](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/55710/16729).

*I was typing while the linked answers came up.*

Comment: > *And the enemies of your hero would be able to* This point can not be stressed enough

Comment: > *at least as expensive as the energy bill for the equivalent energy of the teleported mass* Holy cow that's expensive, like $30M a bullet.

Comment: The teleportation technology hasn't been invented yet, except by another character in the story that is an ally of the hero. The hero has his own personal mad scientist buddy. You do bring up a good point about power, that I'll have to address. Think of the network as an underground type system. Designed for and utilised exclusively by the Hero. A bit like how Spider-Man designed and built his web shooters. But you do make good observations on the logistics of teleportation which I thank you for.

Comment: @Ledav When only two persons doing it and only for bullets, it is too expensive. It doesn't make economic sense. The mad scientist is actually insane and probably crazy rich (or has little regard for the children who discover the teleportation machine in the park). Instead, economy points to Andreas Heese idea of the belt-like system with Daerdemandt's idea of a railgun; except those aren't too powerful at handheld sizes. I'll expand the answer with that. Of course, if energy is not a problem you could get away with a laser rifle (rifle, because you need space for the optics).

Comment: > *aren't too powerful at handheld sizes* I've seen pistol-sized homemade railgun that was giving around 100-150 m/s, and railgun is more efficient on higher speeds. However, battery of capacitors was a separate unit to be carried in a backpack and it was responsible for most of the device's cost.

Comment: @Daerdemandt that seems slow compared to the [Speed of a Bullet](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/1999/MariaPereyra.shtml). And, yeah, energy is the main problem - at least for military applications you could have a BigDog or similar for carry, same goes for the lasers.

Comment: > *seems slow* Well, that could be solved both by manufacturing  the thing in a factory and using better capacitors. Capacitors were the main problem for those hobbyists because they were so expensive. It's not an energy per se, but vessel that can dispatch shot's energy at sufficient speed, like a rubber for a slingshot.

Answer (score 29):

If you have the ability to accurately teleport handgun cartridges, why not send the project directly at the victim with the appropriate kinetic energy?

http://animagraffs.com/how-a-handgun-works-1911-45/

As you can see from the animation, the bullets going into a semi automatic handgun will have to enter the magazine and push down the magazine follower and compress the magazine spring. So teleporting bullets will already need to have a kinetic energy component as well.

Teleportation in principle can be done by describing the position and energy of every molecule or atom in the bullet, and then translating the information into a new set of coordinates representing the new position of the bullet. This is why it seems much simpler to teleport the bullet directly into the target. The shooter needs to accurately describe the needed coordinates to the teleport operator and then the deed is done.

Alternate ideas of teleportation like opening miniature wormholes will need a similar set of coordinates and the "shooter" as a forward observer who can aim the wormhole at the target.

Comment: Unless it is the style of teleportation that requires equipment at both ends. Then it can only go in between the base and the gun

Comment: @Catprog Put the receiver in the barrel, no need to reload, no need of a clip. Lightweight weapon and infinite ammo ;)

Comment: There was a gun in Star Trek:DS9 that acted like a teleporter, firing through walls to hit the target.

Comment: Or just beam a blob of metal into the victim's brain.

Comment: You may want to replace "energy" with "enthalpy" in this post.

Comment: @Richard And the Federation guns in *The Apocalypse Troll* (David Weber) sent their plasma through hyperspace to the target.  While in theory it could have fired through a wall (or armor) they lacked the targeting systems to do so, they did it to avoid enemy shielding.

Answer (score 23):

Maybe ammunition is **fabricated on the spot** by some wearable equipment, out of abundant, mundane, raw materials, and only energy is required. No teleportation is even needed, but you'll need to accommodate the existence of very small, very fast 3D printers, or some other sort of advanced fabrication tech.

I think this is how many things are explained in the Mass Effect series: the player's armor contains a "microfabricator" of some sort, and can spontaneously produce all kinds of complicated objects (from disposable one-use carbon blades, to complex devices, containing programmed electronics). Not sure what raw materials they use in the Mass Effect universe.

Comment: For ammo specifically in Mass Effect the solution was to explain it as tiny (maybe even microscopic) bits of metal that were shaved off a large block and accelerated to relativistic speeds. In Mass Effect 1, this meant unlimited ammo.  For gameplay reasons, this was changed in Mass Effect 2 and 3 and "ammo" returned in the form of heat sink clips.

Comment: _Rogue Trooper_ also used ammunition fabrication.  The game never explained how it worked (and I never read the comics it was based off of). The trooper would just pick up dropped guns and shove them into his backpack which would (over time) fabricate more ammunition.  It wasn't *fast* but it didn't have to be.

(Side note: great FPS if you want to feel like a supersoldier the plot says you are)

Comment: I think in mass effect, they use "omnigel" which is actually a closely-packed clump of nanobots and associated materials, which assemble themselves into whatever shape you need. So your omnitool can easily convert it's small stockpile of omnigel into a knife or a wrench, and if you have a bigger supply, you can make bigger objects.

Comment: True and quite comprehensible to the reader if given a little attention.  Rudy Rucker's "Post Singular" describes nanites which are the cutting edge technology of the near future in the book.  The nanites are described as biosynthetic, reversible, finite-state machines plus molecular recombinators (fabs) which function in concert like cellular automata.  This description leads to the potential for such devices to deconstruct objects into inert matter on one end of a teleportation device, in the process capturing the entire molecular state of the object, and reconstruct on the other end.

Comment: I've seen the word "minifacturing" used to describe this sort of thing.  I like that word.

Answer (score 12):

There are already some very good answers on the topic of teleportation, so i shall not cover that. Instead, i would like to provide you with some different solutions to your problem, and some insight what that would mean for firefights:

- Maybe your guns are coilguns, requiring energy (which CAN be obtained wireless), and magnetic bullets. But only the bullets. So a standard clip might hold hundreds of them...
- Maybe your hero has a small backpack holding the rounds, which are then fed to the guns via a belt-like system attached to his arms (or even implanted?).
- Any maybe you don't WANT your hero to have unlimited ammo? Reloading makes your shots count for more, requires tactical thinking, and gives you less headache in some situations (see below). Also, running out of ammo completely can give some suspense and dramatic moments to your story (or whatever it is you are doing :) )
- I am not sure if you are aware that an automatic weapon with unlimited / quickly replenishing ammo creates some drastic problems. For one, firearms do overheat quickly, even melting the barrel. I was a machine gunner in the (german) army, and we had to exchange the barrels on our MG3 every 100-200 shots. And for that, we already had gloves made of asbestos... and for good reason. I imagine that in a pistol, the heat dissipation will be worse or at least not better, so your rate of fire will be very limited even with teleporting bullets. Then why implement this technology? Your hero could reload any time he needs to wait for his gun to cool down.
- If you mastered the cooling problem to get weapons with no heat problems and infinite bullets... a single man with an automatic weapon can hold any tight spot for DAYS without his enemies having much chances of charging him. This guy can just spray bullets at you all day. Literally.

Comment: "Belt fed backpacks" are pretty darn close to my favorite gun ever. Its from a (now dead) table top RPG called Alpha Omega (for reference, stats and other numbers are comparable to D&D only with a higher cap; everything was pretty much balanced out to 100).  One of the weapons, the Raust Roomcleaner, was a full-auto shotgun that was magnetically fed from a backpack.  20 pounds of steel ball bearings were sufficient for 5 minutes of continuous fire.  And it was as deadly as it sounded 2d10 per shot.

Comment: I was going to add an answer but I feel it would be to close to your first point. That one is like in the first Mass Effect, the lore went that the gun had a "magazine" but it was more along the lines of a solid piece of tungsten that the gun shaved bits off to shoot there by having basically unlimited amounts of ammo as a very tiny portion was shot at very high speeds. The only thing you had to worry about was the heat. In the two games that came after they brought back the reload mechanic but explained it away as switching out heat sinks.

Answer (score 8):

There is no amount of hand waving that could come close to glossing over how something such as your setup would work.  Teleportation, and thus wormholes are merely theoretical as far as anyone knows, and they would require extremely large amounts of exotic energy (negative energy) to make them work for anything larger than things near the [plank scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length).  No one has ever observed a wormhole.  This concept may be confused with [quantum teleportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation), however the two, transporting matter vs transporting information, are very much different processes.

Teleporting matter, anything the size of an atom or larger, would depend on the theory of [Einstein-Rosen bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole), better known as wormholes, which derive from General Relativity Theory.  The energies involved are so large that if we, as a species, started trying to gather and store all of our energy for that purpose, we would not be able to collect enough matter and energy to make a wormhole for a very long time into the future.  Building a wormhole would require similar resources to trying to build a black hole as the two operate on  a similar scale of warping space-time.

I would suggest, as you have already guessed, to keep this in the realm of sci-fi and not try to explain it too much.  [Other commentators](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/theoretically-how-much-energy-would-it-take-for-a-wormhole.784285/) on this topic seem to agree as well.

> I'd avoid real physics terms for something like that. Instead have ultradimensional scissors that cut spacetime and sewed it into somewhere else.
>
> I agree with Alqr, wormholes [...] are so out-there that events such as that it is for the better if it isn't specified how it is happening, just that it is happening and what the consequences are.

That said, I do not think you will even need the triangulation bit because in principle, as far as my limited awareness on the matter goes, there is nothing which prevents the mouths of wormholes from changing their locations without severing the link between the two.  You might lean a little on how quantum teleportation works to see what I mean in that regard.  Einstein called this "spooky action at a distance".  If conserving the energy to keep the wormhole open is a concern in this case, then you may be trying too hard to explain the inexplicable.

Comment: “Teleportation, and thus wormholes” — there are useful teleportation concepts that don’t use wormholes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good point.  The only that I am aware of involve capturing the state of matter of an object, transmitting the information about that state then reconstructing a molecular copy with local materials.  That though is a rather intensive process, also well beyond our current ability with complex objects.  This answer would certainly be better if that were mentioned.  Any other suggestions before I update it?

Answer (score 4):

A Wizard did it.

Really, a sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.  So introduce a source of sufficiently advanced technology.  If you don't want the cultural and societal etc changes related to that, make it a one-off event.

There are some aliens.  These aliens do what they want.  One of the things the aliens did once was give some humans a some handguns.

These handguns reloaded themselves when you pushed a button on them.

They are also opaque to every sensor known to human kind.

More than one of them was dismantled.  Once done so, it became a completely normal handgun.  The button stopped working.  The button wasn't hooked up to anything.  Sensor tech aimed at it while it was dismantled showed complete opacity, followed by a completely normal gun, seemingly in an instant.

When they tried to use it as a spaceship engine, the button stopped working.  It started working again when they brought it back to Earth.

Your hero has two of these guns.  They are reasonably valuable, but 100s of 1000s of them exist.  We don't know why the aliens made them.  We don't know how they work.

A Wizard did it.

Answer (score 3):

Using teleportation to solve reloading problem is similar to using time machine to get around sleep disorder. Sure, it's doable, but would require really modified world where such advanced things are pretty common. You're not going for that, are you?

If you need more shots, you can research other ways of launching your bullets - or ditch bullets altogether and use other types of guns (with their respective drawbacks of course).

There are actually quite some options in that venue:

### Don't use ammo

#### Shoot blanks instead

Using airsoft-like model with blowback, also equipped to make bright flashes and loud *bang*s would trick some people. This, of course, is just a decoy to hide main weapon/power that actually kills enemies leaving gunshot-like wounds.

This would also explain how protagonist is able to hit a single target while going macedonian-style.

Although police could let lack of spent casings slide, lack of actual bullets would be really suspicious to them, so there's an inherent thing going on with them discovering that feature, keeping it secret as a part of investigation, someone leaking that info to enemies, someone figuring out what the actual weapon/power is, someone framing the hero through *not* using bullets too, etc.

And, of course, hero can use actual guns too - for example, when he knows that enemy knows his secret but enemy does not know he knows, so enemy expects blanks.

### Don't use gunpowder

There are other ways to store energy - and to dump sufficient quantity into projectile's speed. Railgun (flashy but barrels deteriorate quickly), Gauss gun (ferromagnetic projectiles only, efficiency around 1% is considered ok), Thomson gun (more efficient but projectioes are a bit more expensive) etc.

You can even still use exploding stuff, just not gunpowder. When a cartridge works, gunpowder does not *detonate*, it [*deflagrates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflagration). You could use other, more potent explosive. If you prevent it from detonating - like, you take a droplet of it and spray it over significantly larger volume and *then* you ignite it (somewhat similar to how combustion engine works). Detonation would just tear the gun apart.

Thus, you can boost mag capacity by reusing most of space that was occupied by gunpowder before. You could get somewhere around hundred shots per mag this way - and carry lots of spares too.

Those all are, of course, more expensive than regular guns - but they work under current tech and are probably cheaper than teleportation would be.

### Don't use teleportation

Have you tried running them numbers? How much lead judgement does your hero typically dispense? How much can he carry? How often would he have to refill under these constraints? It may happen that network of refilling points and also some drone-delivered ammo drops would be simply cheaper and provide same effect.

### Don't use projectiles

If we ditch projectiles, we don't have to carry supply of those. Of course, there *is* a need for power, but battery capacity can be handwaved a bit because not-so-distant future. Network of refill stations can double as electromobile-recharging stations - and even be profitable in itself.

There's obvious option of *asers but some sound shenanigans or some new type of energy gun may probably work too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want several ideas for reloading, I suggest watching [*Equilibrium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilibrium_(film)).  The ["Not without incident"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4weEXyoXZKs) shootout has neat ideas in this regard, for all that it falls into the standard chop-socky trope of the mooks just standing round waiting to be massacred.  The whole Gun-kata idea might be of interest anyway for your dual-handgun-equipped hero.

Answer (score 2):

How about a compromise between the various solutions presented here:

The guns have some sort of handwavium power source and fire silicon oxide darts.  (You need darts instead of bullets because it's nowhere near as dense as bullet material.)  There's a nanotech assembler in the grip of the gun that extracts nearby silicon oxide and forms it into more darts.

In battle he is limited to whatever is in the magazine.  However, out of battle he can lay a gun down on the ground or ideally rocks (of whatever size, sand is fine) and it will reload itself at whatever rate the fabricator works.

Perhaps it can work with a variety of materials, allowing it to absorb nearby metals to forge darts from also.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody said that it is impossible, but then one came who did not know, and just did it.

Enter the...

## Advanced Munitions Entanglement Delivery System (AMEDS)

Using a process which on first sight is very hard, but on second sight is just a trivial spin-off of the run-of-the-mill fusion drive in the spaceship of your hero, the A.C.M.E. corporation has created this brand new, sturdy, yet cheap delivery system. By the long-established sub-quantum entanglement invented back in 3409 (standard solar year), the ammunition holder of your handgun is entangled with the dispenser back in your household.

Due to the well-known property that such entanglement is implicitely cryptographically secure (any measurement or other modification of the connection will not work -at all-), you can rest assured that only you, and not your enemies will get ahold of your bullets, and they are completely tamper-safe.

While every child knows that teleportation to arbitrary spots - like inside the body of your enemy - is physically quite impossible (we are working on it though, and are looking forward to letting you know in our *hugely* entertaining campaign next year), teleporting from the ingress unit in your home to your mobile bullet magazine is the best way to have huge amounts of shots at your disposal, while lugging around only minimal weight.

We are happy to take your orders on this system, as well as diverse options, at our hypernet addr *** CONNECTION LOST.

Comment: Except that's not how quantum entanglement works.  Quantum entanglement allows *existing* particles to exhibit "spooky action at a distance", and potentially transmit *information* instantaneously between entangled particles, but it does not allow the instantaneous movement of matter or energy.

Comment: @HopelessN00b, for customer questions, please contact our Customer Satisfaction Represantative over on Alpha Centauri; she will be more than happy and willing to make your experience with our weapon systems as fruitful as possible!

Comment: @HopelessN00b transmitting *information* is dubious and would likely give FTL as well. However, there *is* a tradeoff between information and energy, basically with a big computer you can compute ways to produce energy on spot and transmit them. Conversion rate would be terrible OFC but that's at least theoretically possible.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the mass and energy requirement, it seems impractical to have the ammo appear inside the gun (in a clip, magazine, or otherwise).  May I suggest that the ammo be teleported in stacks to a unit attached to the belt of the hero.  The hand gun would not have a clip or magazine, but would be designed to have the bullets fed into the bottom of the grips.  Kinda like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vf76iM1E3fk), but directly into the gun.  I feel like this has been done in some anime.

Answer (score 0):

With that technology, I would go for particle accelerator. So your gun will turn molecules in the air into bullets that would fly at, say 0.1c to the target. Great deal of the energy will be lost during the flight but when it connects even at 0.01c, the target will be no more.